# changing background image of button each time when it is tapped in IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an IPhone application in which i want to change the background image of the button each time when it is tapped,ie if it follow it needs to be unfollow when it is tapped and viceverse.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface XXX: UIViewController // whatever
{
    BOOL btnImageState;
}

// etc.

@implementation XXX

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"follow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)click:(UIButton *)btn
{
    if (btnImageState)
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"follow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unfollow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    btnImageState = !btnImageState;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want use button as toggle button than use flag(BOOL) variable and set it according your requirements. But if you are setting button image more than once than use it as I show below.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{ 

   if([sender tag] == 1)
        {
            [yourbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btnSegment1.tag = 2;// Here i reset tag. you can set tag according your requirements so you can use button next for next click as you want

        }
        else if([sender tag] == 2)
        {
            [yourbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             yourbutton.tag = 3;// Here i reset tag. you can set tag according your requirements so you can use button next for next click as you want

        }
    // and so on.....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i did it programatically. Hope this will help you.

```
-(IBAction) pause:(id)sender
{
UIButton  *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"];
[button1 setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(208, 380.0, 60.0, 60.0);
[self.view addSubview:button1];
}
- (IBAction) aMethod
{
button1.hidden=YES;

UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 addTarget:self 
            action:@selector(pause:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button2Image.png"];
[button1 setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[button1 setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(208, 380.0, 60.0, 60.0);
[self.view addSubview:button1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static int tapCount = 0;
- (IBAction) buttonTapped :(id)sender {
    tapCount++;

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",tapCount];
    [yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

It will depend on you how you want to load image with what name, and number of images. Accordingly you can customize.